# python process that runs socket connection returns ready when process is not completed

Tags: python, sockets, multiprocessing

I am writing a program that concurrently creates socket clients and sends some commands.  I am using the following function to spawn the process':

```
result = pool.apply_async(function, (arguments,))
```

I am checking if the process' have completed so that I can get the return value I use the following:

```
result.ready()
```

The issue is `ready()` is returning `True` when the `socket.connect()` call is issued within the function, but the function has not completed.  Any thoughts as to why?  If I comment out the connect and run the function without socket functions, the ready signal returns `False` until the process is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved.  The issue was due to my program passing a string as the port instead of an integer.  Thus, the process did die.  Since I didn't have a try except looking for the exception, the process died and I did not know.